# can't find my inflated view in pager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

I have some specific `pager` called `JazzyViewPager`, which is a classic `ViewPager` with some effects.

In my pager adapter method `instantiateItem(), @param(ViewGroup container,final int position)`, I put

```
int pic = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
ImageView img = new ImageView(getActivity());
                img.setBackgroundResource(pic);
                container.addView(img,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 LayoutInflater inflater_pager =
                        (LayoutInflater) container.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View vi = inflater_pager.inflate(R.layout.tag_list, null);    
                container.addView(vi,0);
```

where the `tag_list` layout corresponds to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Nikita Hrist"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I can see the picture I set as a background but I can't find the text. How can I deal with that ?

Comment: Try dropping the second parameter in `container.addView(vi,0)`.

Comment: First of all it depends on `container`. Second `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` says that image will fill all `container` so everything works fine.

Comment: @MikeM. it still does not work

Comment: @Foxinsocks I tried to replace it by `container.addView(img)` but it did not change

Comment: @MikeM. in fact, I am a total newbe to `android` and in this code I realize that the `instantiateItem` returns `img`, so to check I returned `vi` so it displays correctly. So how returning both img and the inflated textview ? I thought `container.add` would take care of that automatically...

Comment: Well, I would remove the ImageView instantiation from the code and put the ImageView in the layout xml you're inflating. When you inflate the layout, use `findViewById()` to get the ImageView and set it's background, then return the whole shebang.